# When a BECs mixture Hamiltonian posses a Galileian invariance?

Tags: symmetry, bose-einstein-condensate

I'm currently studying BECs mixtures (with and without the presence of a coupling term between them).
While studying the symmetries of the system I stuck on the following question: does this system posses the Galileian invariance as if not, what are the condition the boost have to satisfy to have it?

The Hamiltonian of the system is the following:

$H = \sum_{\sigma = a, b} (\frac{p_\sigma^2}{2m} + g_\sigma n_\sigma^2) + g_{ab}n_a n_b - \frac{\hbar \Omega}{2}\sqrt{n_a n_b}\cos\phi$

and the Galilean transformation is given by $G = \exp(i \frac{m v r}{\hbar})$.\

If I apply the transformation I obtain that the new Hamiltonian is:
$H' = H + \sum_{\sigma}\frac{m v^2}{2} + v p_\sigma$.

So it has no such symmetry, right? Or there's something I miss? Because online I found that only the spin-orbit coupled BECs Hamiltonian isn't Galilean invariant, while nothing is said for the normal case making me thinking that maybe it has G. symmetry.

My doubt stems from the fact that when studying the case in which BECs move with a superfluid velocity, one has phenomena such as energy instabilities (due to the velocity $v = v_a + v_b$ of the system), while those related to the relative velocity $v = v_a- v_b$ - referred to as counterlow instability - are said to be the result of the system's explicit breaking of Galileian symmetry (differently form the case in which the system moves with the same velocity).